# Write to Next Blank row Excel - Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

My code writes data to excel however it is overwriting the same row and columns. I do not want to overwrite the row that has the column titles and the rows after that if it has data in it.

Steps
1 enter column heading
2 enter data in rows/columns
3 if column heading are there don't write column heading
4 if row/columns filled go to next
5 repeat 1-4

My code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    //Create blank workbook
                      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

                      //Create a blank sheet
                      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet( " Employee Info ");

                      //Create row object
                      XSSFRow row;

                      //This data needs to be written (Object[])
                      Map < String, Object[] > clientinfo = new TreeMap < String, Object[] >();
                      clientinfo.put( "1", new Object[] {
                         "PayRoll Status", "Week #", "Pay Date","End Date" });

                      clientinfo.put( "2", new Object[] {
                      CycleStatus, WeekID, DateId, EndDateId });


                      //Iterate over data and write to sheet
                      Set < String > keyid = clientinfo.keySet();
                      int rowid = 0;

                      for (String key : keyid) {
                         row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
                         Object [] objectArr = clientinfo.get(key);
                         int cellid = 0;

                         for (Object obj : objectArr){
                            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
                            cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                         }
                      }
                      //Write the workbook in file system
                      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                         new File("C:/PayrollSync/Pre-Payroll.xlsx"));

                      workbook.write(out);
                      out.close();
                      System.out.println("Prepayroll.xlsx written successfully");
```

---

This is the solution i came up with however it write the count of the rows is there any way to take it off

```
  String excelFilePath = "C://PayrollSync//Pre-Payroll.xlsx";
                            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
                            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

                            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                            //CycleStatus, WeekID, DateId, EndDateId
                            Object[][] bookData = {
                                    {CycleStatus,WeekID,DateId,EndDateId},

                            };

                            int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();

                            for (Object[] aBook : bookData) {
                                Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);

                                int columnCount = 0;

                                Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
                                cell.setCellValue(rowCount);

                                for (Object field : aBook) {
                                    cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                                    if (field instanceof String) {
                                        cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                                    } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                                        cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                                    }
                                }

                            }



                            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C://PayrollSync//Pre-Payroll.xlsx");
                            workbook.write(outputStream);
                            inputStream.close();
                            outputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do it in this way:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import no.tollpost.web.termodash.rest.report.excel.model.ExcelReportDTO;
import no.tollpost.web.termodash.rest.report.excel.model.RowDTO;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public final class ExcelGenerator {
  
  private ExcelGenerator() {
  }

  public static void getExcelVersion(final OutputStream outputStream) {
    try {
        final Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
        generateReport(book);
        book.write(outputStream);
    } catch (final IOException | OpenXML4JRuntimeException e) {
        //log.warn("Failed to build excel report", e);
    }
  }

  private static void generateReport(final Workbook book) {
    final Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("Sheet_name");
    final List<String> columnNames = getColumnNames();
    final List<RowDTO> rows = getRows(getYourData()); // get your data as list of your DTOs

    generateTableHeader(sheet, book, columnNames);
    generateTableRows(sheet, rows);

    IntStream.range(0, columnNames.size()).forEach(sheet::autoSizeColumn);
  }

  private List<YourDTO> getYourData() {
  return // Your data as List (each element will be row in the excel sheet)
  }

  private static List<String> getColumnNames() {
    return Lists.newArrayList("column_name_1", "column_name_2", "column_name_3");
  }

  private static List<RowDTO> getRows(final List<YourDTO> data) {
        final List<RowDTO> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, data.size()).forEach(i -> {
            final List<String> cellsMapper = new ArrayList<>();
            cellsMapper.add(data.get(i).getSomeProperty());
            cellsMapper.add(data.get(i).getOtherProperty());
            cellsMapper.add(data.get(i).getThirdProperty());
            cellsMapper.add(data.get(i).getFourthProperty());
            
            rows.add(new RowDTO(cellsMapper));
        });

        // rows.sort(Comparator.comparing(row -> row.getData().get(3)));

        return rows;
  }

  private static void generateTableHeader(final Sheet sheet, final Workbook workbook, final List<String> cellTitles) {
    final Row tabellHeader = sheet.createRow(0);

    IntStream.range(0, cellTitles.size()).forEach(cellNummer -> {
        final Cell cell = tabellHeader.createCell(cellNummer);
        cell.setCellValue(cellTitles.get(cellNummer));
        setHeaderCellStyle(cell, workbook, cellTitles.get(cellNummer));
    });
  }

  private static void setHeaderCellStyle(final Cell celle, final Workbook workbook, final String celleTittel) {
    if (!celleTittel.isEmpty()) {
        celle.setCellStyle(getHeaderCellStyle(workbook));
    }
  }

  private static CellStyle getHeaderCellStyle(final Workbook workbook) {
    final CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.PALE_BLUE.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    final Font font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    style.setFont(font);

    return style;
  }

  private static void generateTableRows(final Sheet sheet, final List<RowDTO> rows) {
    IntStream.range(0, rows.size()).forEach(rowNUmber -> {
        final Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNUmber + 1);

        IntStream.range(0, rows.get(rowNUmber).getData().size())
                 .forEach(cellNumber -> setCellValue(cellNumber, rowNUmber, row, rows));
    });
  }

  private static void setCellValue(final int cellNumber, final int rowNumber, final Row row, final List<RowDTO> rows) {
    final Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);
    cell.setCellValue(rows.get(rowNumber).getData().get(cellNumber));
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
  }
}

final class RowDTO {

    private final List<String> data;

    public RowDTO(final List<String> data) {
    this.data = data;
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
       return data;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this.. However I already have this in a class could it be formatted not to be written in separate methods?

Comment: Also this seems so complicated is there a simpler way or coding this?

Comment: the code i put above is already in a for loop within eclipse i just need to write it to a excel document and every time it loops the values of CycleStatus, WeekID, DateId and EndDateId will be different if you could help me implement this solution it would be appreciated

Comment: If the code you listed above is already in a for loop it means that you creat new workbook and sheet each time you iterate, i.e. you get several excel files with only one row each. Is it that what you want to get?

Comment: oh no i just wanted to repeatedly enter variable that hold string text into each row then when it loops around it does it agian to the next row and then agian to the next row

Comment: Only problem is that it write the nunber in the first column and i dont want that

Comment: The above code will keep the file open till the looping is done

Comment: It seems that you only reuse the cell you instantiated in the first loop. It's necessary to create a new cell per new piece of data. (I mean in your new code snippet).

Comment: can you give me a visual example of what i need to do

Comment: That's why I posted my code in the first place. If you don't want to use RowDTO you can replace it with List<List<String>> where inner list is "row" and outer list is the list of "rows". So it's only necessary to populate this List<List<String>> with your data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166769/discussion-between-jonathan-and-contrapost).

Comment: The problem I had with your code is that I don't know how to link it to my class. the code that I originally posted above is in one class and your have one class with many methods.

Comment: t work rite now i cant answer or see what you type will get back to you later.Firewall is blocking the chat.